# Python - Nesting a dict/array by value

Tags: python

I want to nest a dict/array by a level value. The dict is already sorted but just 1 dimensional.

It looks like this:

```
tables = {
    1: {
        'level': 1
    },
    2: {
        'level': 2
    },
    3: {
        'level': 3
    },
    4: {
        'level': 3
    },
    5: {
        'level': 2
    },
    6: {
        'level': 3
    }
}
```

If the level value of the following item is higher then the previous, the the item shall be nested in the previous item. For example ITEM 1's level is 1, ITEM 2's level is 2, so ITEM 2 is moving into ITEM 1.

It shall look like this then:

```
tables = {
    1: {
        'level': 1,
        'tables': {
            2: {
                'level': 2,
                'tables': {
                    3: {
                        'level': 3,
                    },
                    4: {
                        'level': 3
                    }
                }
            },
            5: {
                'level': 2,
                'tables': {
                    6: {
                        'level': 3,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried ... currently you haven't stated a problem or question but rather gone for the "do all my work for me please" approach

Answer (score 0):

It is classical recursion exercise:

```
def get_next_level(level):
    result = {}
    result[level] = {'level': level}
    if level > max(tables.keys()):
        return None
    next_level = get_next_level(level+1)
    if next_level is not None:
        result[level].update({'tables': next_level})
    return result
```

Solution is short and easy. You should start computation like this:

```
res_table = {}
res_table[1] = {'level': 1}
res_table[1].update({'tables': get_next_level(2)})
```